# How to compare in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

How to compare in shell script?

Or, why the following script prints nothing?

```
x=1
if[ $x = 1 ] then echo "ok" else echo "no" fi
```

Comment: you need a ; after ] and a space after if:

`if [ $x = 1 ]; then echo "ok" ; else echo "no" ; fi`

Comment: @Sergio it gives `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`then'`

Comment: @Hossein it gives `1=1: command not found`

Comment: maybe my bash files (on the system) are with some problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With numbers, use `-eq`, `-ne`, ... for equals, not equals, ...

```
x=1
if [ $x -eq 1 ]
then 
  echo "ok" 
else 
  echo "no" 
fi
```

And for others, use `==` not `=`.

Comment: By using -eq and the ; after ] it gives `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`then'`

Comment: Yes, in fact you have to let a "space" before and after each "["... I just edited a valid code.

Comment: @Tom do not use '==' instead of '='.  The 'test' command (aka '['), whether builtin or external, often accepts '==', but '=' is more universal.  Using '==' unnecessarily limits the portability of the script.

Answer (score 6):

Short solution with shortcut AND and OR:

```
x=1
(( $x == 1 )) && echo "ok" || echo "no"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could compare in shell in two methods

1. Single-bracket syntax ( `if [ ]` )
2. Double-parenthesis syntax ( `if (( ))`)

---

### Using Single-bracket syntax

Operators :-

> `-eq`    is equal to
>
> `-ne`    is not equal to
>
> `-gt`    is greater than
>
> `-ge`    is greater than or equal to
>
> `-lt`    is less than
>
> `-le`    is less than or equal to

In Your case :-

```
x=1
if [ $x -eq 1 ]
then 
  echo "ok" 
else 
  echo "no" 
fi
```

### Double-parenthesis syntax

Double-parentheses construct is also a mechanism for allowing `C`-style manipulation of variables in Bash, for example, `(( var++ )).`

In your case :-

```
x=1
if (( $x == 1 )) # C like statements 
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language. With bash, you can use `==` operator. Otherwize you may use `-eq` `-lt` `-gt` for equals, lowerthan, greaterthan.

```
$ x=1
$ if [ "$x" == "2" ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
no
```

Edit: added spaces arround `==` and tested with 2.

Comment: You need spaces around the "==" -- try your command with `[ "$x"=="2" ]` and you'll see that's true too.  You need `[ "$x" = "1" ]` or `[ $x -eq 1 ]`, or with bash `[[ $x == 1 ]]` or `(( x == 1 ))`

Comment: thanks for that correction, manual indent issue.. But [ ] works too.